# Messed something up, and now I can't get into wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, fatal-error

I did something to one of the files (it was some months ago, can't remember which ones) and now when I go to the wp-admin it shows me an error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_term_meta() (previously declared in /home/finerybo/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php:1757) in /home/finerybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/buyshop/framework/inc/taxonomy-metadata.php on line 103

I want to uninstall the old theme and install a new one, but how can I get back into my wp-admin?

Comment: Delete the theme per FTP?

Comment: But if I can't even get into wp-admin, doesn't mean it's something other than the theme which is broken?

Comment: The error message is telling you *exactly* where the problem is. Your theme has a function declared that is part of WordPress.

Comment: So deleting the theme would solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's what the error message is telling you. :)

Comment: you can also rename the offending theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, by switching the theme in the database.